# Let $\omega$ be a 1-form, and $X, Y$ vector fields. Then $d\omega(X, Y) = X \omega(Y) - Y \omega(X) - \omega([X, Y])$

Tags: smooth-manifolds, differential-forms

These are defined in a smooth manifold, $d$ is the exterior derivative, and $[\cdot, \cdot]$ is the Lie Bracket. I tried opening up these in coordinates, but it got overwhelming pretty quickly. Anyone knows a smart way to prove this?

Comment: Can you please show us what you got when you tried expanding these using coordinates?

Comment: $\omega = f_i dx^i$, $d \omega = df_i \wedge dx^i = \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x^j} dx^j \wedge dx^i$. $d\omega(X, Y) = \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x^j} dx^j \wedge dx^i (X, Y)$.

Comment: and when I try putting $X, Y$ in coordinates, the amount of indexes becomes too much for me too handle confidently.

Comment: So $d\omega(X, Y) = \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j}\left(X^j Y^i - Y^j X^i \right)$. That's all. Would you like to try the other three terms?

Comment: OK, I arrived at the same result, but how can this be the same as $X\omega(Y) - Y\omega(X) - \omega([X, Y])$? I guess I'll try opening this one up as well.

Comment: Yes, go ahead!  .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "smart" way to prove this (as one finds in the standard textbooks) is to check that the right-hand side defines a tensor; i.e., it is linear (in each slot) over the space of $C^\infty$ functions. After that, by multilinearity and the observed linearity over $C^\infty$ functions, we can just check for $X=\partial/\partial x^i$ and $Y=\partial/\partial x^j$ (for which the Lie bracket term of course disappears). But this is easy.

Comment: By definition of tensors, it suffices to verify that both sides of the equation are equal when evaluated at basic vectors, right? But doesn't it also means that $d /omega (X, Y) = X /omega(Y) - Y /omega(X)$? The expression on the right hand side is also a skew-symmetric tensor, and it also has the same value on pairs of basic vectors. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: No, the formula you wrote down without the Lie bracket is *not* a tensor. It is not linear over $C^\infty$ functions. Try putting in $fY$ instead of $Y$ (or $fX$ instead of $X$).

Comment: I get it, it is a tensor when we look at vector fields as a vector space over real numbers, but it is not when we consider it to be a module over smooth real valued functions. Is this right?

Comment: Right. That's a very important distinction :)